# notification when program is in background iOS 4

Tags: iphone, background, notifications, multitasking

We are looking for a way to timeout an iPhone application, and have tried several methods:

NSTimer that resets after an action
LocalNotification that resets after an action

Both are close, but suffer from unique issues:

NSTimer: When the phone sleeps, the timer will not fire
LocalNotification:  When the app is in the background, the notification is displayed, we don't have a way to have the application have to receive the notification.

Asking the group if this sounds correct, or if there is maybe some point above that I am missing that would allow this to work.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do realize that when your app is in a suspended state, you won't receive any notifications -- and this is right in the documentation. There are only 3 classes of applications that can receive notifications: Audio applications (like iPod and analogues), location based applications, and voip apps. Your plist has to be set up correctly if your app is one of those applications.

Comment: I have an audio recording app and i have registered it as a background app in the plist file. When it is recording in the background, I want to be notified of any call or SMS so that I can stop recording, save the file. How  should I receive the notifications in the background?