# How to show a UILocalNotification when ASINetworkQueue finishes all requests?

Tags: iphone, ios, queue, asihttprequest, uilocalnotification

I'm using [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) to download multiple files while the iPhone app is running in the background. I want to present a `UILocalNotification` when the queue finishes.
The following delegate method isn't called until the app is resumed:

```
- (void)queueFinished:(ASINetworkQueue *)aQueue
{

    NSLog(@"Queue finished");

    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationState] == UIApplicationStateBackground) {
        UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
        localNotification.alertBody = NSLocalizedString(@"All downloads completed");        
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:localNotification];
        [localNotification release];
    }
}
```

So, how can I make this notification appear?

Answer (score 1):

The reason your delegate isn't getting called is likely because your app is suspended in the background.  If you are doing some sort of lengthy network process that continues after the user closes the app, you can use `-[UIApplication beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:]` when you start the network tasks so that your application continues running in the background until you're done with the network tasks.  However, it can still expire so you're not guaranteed to get enough time to finish.

Comment: I know that _ASIHTTPRequest_ invokes `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler` when I configure the request with `[request setShouldContinueWhenAppEntersBackground:YES]`. And downloading files in the background works just fine, but I still can't show the notification.

Comment: Didn't know about that feature of ASIHTTPRequest.  In that case, I'm not sure why it's not working...

Answer (score 0):

From previous SO question [notification when program is in background iOS 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3249151/notification-when-program-is-in-background-ios-4)

You do realize that when your app is in a suspended state, you won't receive any notifications -- and this is right in the documentation. There are only 3 classes of applications that can receive notifications: Audio applications (like iPod and analogues), location based applications, and voip apps. Your plist has to be set up correctly if your app is one of those applications.

Comment: Sorry, but this answer is way too generic and does not solve my specific problem. I know how to show local notifications in general. I guess the reason why the delegate method isn't called in background state is because it is invoked with `performSelectorOnMainThread`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
UILocalNotification *localNot = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
localNot.alertBody = @"Your Text";
localNot.alertAction = @"Name on the button";
localNot.fireDate = [NSDate date];
localNot.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNot];
```

What you're doing:

- Create the LocalNotification
- Add the body of your LN
- Add the name of the button which appears on the "alert"
- Set the fireDate to the actual date and time (maybe you need to increase the actual date with 1 or 2 seconds - for this use: `dateByAddingTimeInterval:`)
- Set the soundName (you could also use a custom sound...)
- Schedule / Create the LN

Comment: My problem is not _how_ to show the local notification. The actual problem is how to get `queueFinished` called while running in background state.

Comment: "How to show a UILocalNotification...?" That's why I posted on your question.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have your queue maxConcurrentOperationCount set to 1?

The method setShouldContinueWhenAppEntersBackground:YES is set on a per request basis, and since you have a bunch of ASIHTTPRequest's inside a queue, only one of them may be executing at a time. This means that the other items in your queue haven't even started when you suspend the app, so the OS doesn't know yet to keep that network request alive.

I'm not sure of a solution, but I think this is the reason for what you're seeing.